# Scrapy spider not following links and error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to write my first web crawler / data extractor using scrapy and can't get it follow links. I am also getting an error:

> ERROR: Spider error processing < GET
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unusual_articles>

I know the spider is scanning the page once as I am able to pull out information from an `a` tag and `h1` element I was messing with.

Does anyone know how I could make this follow the links on the page and get rid of the error?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from wikiCrawler.items import WikicrawlerItem
from scrapy.spiders import Rule


class WikispyderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wikiSpyder"

    allowed_domains = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/']

    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unusual_articles']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True), follow=True, callback="parse"),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        links = LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True).extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            item = WikicrawlerItem()
            item['url_from'] = response.url
            item['url_to'] = link.url
            items.append(item)
            print(items)
        return items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Link Extractors, you need to use a special spider class - [`CrawlSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider):

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

class WikispyderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    # ...
```

Here is a simple spider that follows the links from your start url and prints out the page titles:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

from scrapy.spiders import Rule


class WikispyderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "wikiSpyder"

    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unusual_articles']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True), follow=True, callback="parse_link"),
    )

    def parse_link(self, response):
        print(response.xpath("//title/text()").extract_first())
```